# VBA/Excel Spinner output is not a number, screws with excel commands

Tags: vba, excel, spinner

I added a Spinner in my user form that outputs to a text box

```
Private Sub Level_Spinner_Change()

Level_Select.Text = Level_Spinner.Value

End Sub
```

and it is then exported to a different sheet

```
'Write Level into Main Worksheet
Worksheets("Main").Range("E1").Value = Level_Select
```

However, the result in the new sheet is not a number and does not function in the excel commands as a number. For instance,

```
IF(E1<5,E1,"N/A")
```

reports back N/A for all values. If i go to the specific cell, I can click the error message and convert it to a number, but I have no idea how to make it do that automatically or fix the error in the VBA code. I can't

```
Dim Level_Select as Integer
```

anywhere in the code because it either won't run at all, or just reports zero in the exported cell. I can't change .text to .value because it has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inserting the spinner value into the text box it is converted to a string. Just use the original spinner value for pasting to the Excel cell, so it will keep being an integer:

```
Worksheets("Main").Range("E1").Value = Level_Spinner.Value
```

Comment: Well, I could have sworn I tried that one but evidently not. Thank you so very much